# How to replace camelCasing in all files in a folder using Python or c#?

Tags: c#, python, camelcasing

I have a folder that has a mix and match of camelCase and non camel case filenames. I have used this in Python to remove underscores and was hoping I could easily tweak it to replace 'camelCaseExample' with 'camel Case Example':

```
folder = r"C:/....."
import os
pathiter = (os.path.join(root, filename)
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(folder)
    for filename in filenames
)
for path in pathiter:
    newname =  path.replace('_', ' ')
    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path,newname)
```

Could anyone help me edit this to get it working for regex?

I have tried this with no luck:

```
newname =  path.replace('%[A-Z][a-z]%', ' ')
```

I would also be able to use a c# solution if that would be easier

Comment: Why do you have `%` in your regex?

Comment: I must be thinking of SQL.  I have tried it without and still no luck.

Comment: If your goal is to simply replace insert a space between a lowercase alpha followed by an uppercase alpha: `re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', 'camelCaseExample')`. See [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: the issue is when I try to do this with folders, as this seems to apply this to the entire path rather than filename?

Comment: So only apply it to the filename. You are currently joining the filename with the root immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to try regex using the `re` library.

```
import re
new_name = re.sub("(?=[A-Z])", " ", "testFileName")
print(new_name)
```

Will output:

```
test File Name
```

If you want it to be lowercase after this, you could just call

```
new_name = new_name.lower()
```

What the regex is doing is looking for any point immediately before an upper case letter and substituting a space there. This [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/80yuLO/1) will help explain it better.

Comment: This applies the logic to the entire path, rather than just the filename. It also adds a space between words, so it converts 'This File' to 'This   File'. Which creates issues with the entire path.

Comment: How did you handle that in your original underscore version?

Comment: Something like [`os.path.basename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) might be helpful for you.

Comment: the underscore was only part of filename, and never anywhere upstream in path, so was a non issue.

Comment: Yup that was it. THANK YOU!