# Adding space before capital letters in yaml file (flexget config)

Tags: python, regex, replace, camelcasing

I have some problems with the [*FlexGet* Configuration](https://flexget.com/Configuration).

I want to rename and move some movies.

#### Example

For example the movie `"ElPatriota"` (which currently is unable to rename) can not be found in [TheMovieDataBase (tmdb)](https://www.themoviedb.org/) when searching for this title without spaces.

So I need to rename it first to `"El Patriota"` before I can look it up at *tmdb* and move it to his correct directory.

#### What I researched

I saw this function using a regular-expression but I don't know how to implement it on my config or if it's the correct solution for me.

```
re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "WordWordWord")
'Word Word Word'
```

#### FlexGet Config YAML

This is a part of the related config:

```yaml
move movies:
    priority: 3
    template:
      - movies-metainfo
      - telegram
    filesystem:
      path: /downloads/
      recursive: yes
      retrieve: files
      regexp: '.*\.(avi|mkv|mp4)$'
    seen: local
    regexp:
      reject:
        - \b(duo|tri|quadri|tetra|penta)logy\b: {from: title}
        - s\d{2}(e\d{2,})?: {from: title} 
    require_field: 
      - tmdb_name
      - movie_name
    accept_all: yes
    tmdb_lookup:
      language: es
    set:
      title: "{{title|replace('4K','[]')|replace('BD1080','[]')|replace('M1080','[]')}}"  
    move:
      to: "/media/Peliculas/"
      rename: "{{tmdb_name|replace('/','_')|replace(':',' -')|replace(',','')|replace('?','')}}"
      along:
        extensions:
          - sub
          - srt
        subdirs:
          - Subs
      clean_source: 50
```

Comment: Where is that (file-) or movie-name from `"ElPatriota"` ? What is the source for this name ?  Maybe we can add a filter there or find the appropriate FlxGet-plugin.

Comment: The complete name is ```ElPatriotaM1080.www.url.com.mkv``` When the name is ```El Patriota M1080.www.url.com.mkv``` i have no problems because i replace the M1080 for [] and the title can be found at tmdb but without spaces i have no chance to do a lookup at tmdb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Assumptions on construction of search-terms

From your comment I assume the file-name replacing step as input for the search is:

```
    set:
      title: "{{title|replace('4K','[]')|replace('BD1080','[]')|replace('M1080','[]')}}"
```

So the different search-terms (set `title`s) are alternatives (separated by `|` like boolean OR):

```
title|replace('4K','[]')|replace('BD1080','[]')|replace('M1080','[]')
```

See also FlexGet docs:

- [`series` Plugin, Set entry fields](https://flexget.com/Plugins/series/set)
- [`set` Plugin](https://flexget.com/Plugins/set)
- [`manipulate` Plugin](https://flexget.com/Plugins/manipulate)

#### Regex as solution

Assume further that you can use a regular-expression to substitute the title.
Then a regex-substitution adding a space between lower-case and upper-case letters will do:

| Step | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Input | `ElPatriotaM1080.www.url.com.mkv` |
| Wanted | `El Patriota M1080.www.url.com.mkv` |
| Regex | substitute `([a-z])([A-Z])` by `\1 \2` |
| Output | `El Patriota M1080.www.url.com.mkv` |

#### `Manipulate` and `replace` by regex

Appropriate seems the `manipulate` Plugin with action `replace` as sown in [Example 4](https://flexget.com/Plugins/manipulate#example-4):

> You can control how the *regex hits* are output using `\1`, `\2`, etc in format.
>
> ```yaml
> manipulate:
>   - title:
>       replace:            
>         regexp: '(.*)/(.*)/(.*)'
>         format: '\2.\1.\3'
> ```

**⚠️ Caution: Regex matches are ignore-case by default**
Since the regex is case-sensitive (depends on different upper-case and lower-case characters), the default regex-flags of the manipulate replace-by-regex [(IGNORE and UNICODE)](https://github.com/Flexget/Flexget/blob/develop/flexget/plugins/modify/manipulate.py#L146) must be disabled explicitly by surrounding the regex with disabled inline-flag `i` like `(?-i:<regex>)`.

#### Config snippets

In this case it could look like separating the lower-case (first group `([a-z])` and insert by reference `\1`) from upper-case (second group `([A-Z])` and insert by reference `\2`) by a space between.

Additionally disabling the `i` we need to config: `(?-i:([a-z])([A-Z]))`.

```yaml
manipulate:
  - title:
      replace:            
        regexp: '(?-i:([a-z])([A-Z]))'
        format: '\1 \2'
```

or alternatively, without capturing but with a *positive look-ahead*  as `(?=[A-Z])` then inserting a space (with switched-off ignore-case flag):

```yaml
manipulate:
  - title:
      replace:            
        regexp: '(?-i:(?=[A-Z]))'
        format: ' '
```

#### Demo in pure Python

A working demo in pure Python shows how to replace file-names.
It was adapted from [How to replace camelCasing in all files in a folder using Python or c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935339/how-to-replace-camelcasing-in-all-files-in-a-folder-using-python-or-c):

```py
import re

old_name = 'ElPatriotaM1080.www.url.com.mkv'
print(f"Given:           '{old_name}'")

flags=re.I  # default for FlexGet's replace-plugin: ignore-case

regex_1           = '(?=[A-Z])'
regex_1_no_ignore = '(?-i:(?=[A-Z]))'

new_name = re.sub(regex_1, ' ', old_name, flags=flags)
print(f"Regex 1 (I on ): '{new_name}'")
new_name = re.sub(regex_1_no_ignore, ' ', old_name, flags=flags)
print(f"Regex 1 (I off): '{new_name}'")


regex_2           = r'([a-z])([A-Z])'
regex_2_no_ignore = r'(?-i:([a-z])([A-Z]))'

new_name = re.sub(regex_2, r'\1 \2', old_name, flags=flags)
print(f"Regex 2 (I on ): '{new_name}'")
new_name = re.sub(regex_2_no_ignore, r'\1 \2', old_name, flags=flags)
print(f"Regex 2 (I off): '{new_name}'")
```

Prints:

```
Given:           'ElPatriotaM1080.www.url.com.mkv'
Regex 1 (I on ): ' E l P a t r i o t a M1080. w w w. u r l. c o m. m k v'
Regex 1 (I off): ' El Patriota M1080.www.url.com.mkv'
Regex 2 (I on ): 'E lP at ri ot aM1080.w ww.u rl.c om.m kv'
Regex 2 (I off): 'El Patriota M1080.www.url.com.mkv'
```

Both regex-approaches (1+2) have almost the same effect: space inserted before upper-case letters. However, the ignore-case flag (whether "I on" or "I off") has unexpected impact on the result.

Comment: I neither have access to _FlexGet_ nor tested this config. This is just a theoretical answer from research in FlexGet's docs plus my experience of regular-expressions in Python. So please test it and give me feedback how it worked ️

Comment: Man this saved my life!!! definitely with this:
```manipulate:
- title:
replace:
regexp: '(?-i:([a-z])([A-Z]))'
format: '\1 \2'```
the problem has been solved, if I'm honest I still don't understand it but thank you that there are capable people like you to lend a hand. Thanks a lot.